# Python function return 'None' list

Tags: python

I have a function that removes duplicates from a list, and if removed, fills again those blanks with another entry of another list with all possible entries.

Right now, I have a function which does this work, but I don`t know why, at time to store that complete list without duplicates in another list when I call it, it appears as "none". But it works properly.
This is the function:

```
def elimina_Rep(dondeborrar, cantidadNecesaria, fichcompleto):
    sinRep = []                                                 # Donde almacenaremos las NO repetidas
    sinRep_AUX = []                                             # Para borrar en la borrada, (varios ciclos de borrado)
    for elem in dondeborrar:                                    # Primera busqueda de elementos duplicados
        if(elem not in sinRep): sinRep.append(elem)             # Obtenemos una lista sin repeticiones
    if sinRep == dondeborrar : pass                             # Comprobamos que haya diferencia de cantidad entre ambas
    else:
        while(sinRep != sinRep_AUX):
            dif = (cantidadNecesaria - len(sinRep))             # Obtenemos cuantos elementos hemos borrado
            for i in range(0,dif):                              # Generamos tantas nuevas entradas como las que hemos borrado
                sinRep.append(random.choice(fichcompleto))      # Obtenemos una nueva lista completa (pero con posibles repeticiones)    
            for j in sinRep:                                    # Comprobamos que no haya repeticiones de la primera busqueda
                if(j not in sinRep_AUX):                        # Segunda busqueda de elementos duplicados  
                    sinRep_AUX.append(j)                        # Obtenemos una lista sin repeticiones sinRep_AUX desde la primera sin rep  
            if(sinRep == sinRep_AUX): 
                return sinRep_AUX
            else:
                sinRep = sinRep_AUX
                sinRep_AUX = []
```

If I print at the end of the function the content of `sinrep_AUX` (final correct list) all is OK, the problem appears in the calling at time to store it.

```
def gen_Preg(asignatura, porcentaje):
    preguntas = []                                              # Creamos una lista vacia para alamcenar las preguntas
    porc = int((porcentaje/100)*totalpreguntas)                 # Obtenemos cuantas preguntas necesitamos de esa asignatura por %

    # Bucle for para obtener y escribir la 1a vez (con posibles duplicaciones)
    with open(asignatura, 'r') as aPreg:
        fichero = aPreg.read().strip().splitlines()             # Obtenemos el fichero sin posibles espacios
        for i in range(0,porc):
            preguntas.append(random.choice(fichero))

    random.shuffle(preguntas)                                   # Mezclamos las preguntas generadas
    preg_filt = elimina_Rep(preguntas, porc, fichero)           # Tenemos un archivo con preguntas sin repeticiones
    print(preg_filt)
```

Here, the first line shows the content of print `sinRep_AUX` from function `elimina_Rep`, and the last line, shows the content of `preg_filt`, that I suppose that is the list which store the returned list of the function when I call it

```
['Como te llamas?', 'Donde vives?', 'Como tomas apuntes?']
None
```

I've tried to change the return line from `return sinRep_AUX` to `return elimina_Rep(dondeborrar, cantidadNecesaria, fichcompleto)` as I saw in other posts, but it doesn't work

Comment: @C.Nivs: it *may not always* return anything; there is a `return` statement, but buried in a conditional inside of a loop.

Comment: _If I print at the end of the function the content of sinrep_AUX (final correct list) all is OK, the problem appears in the calling at time to store it._ - don't print it, but `return` the list.

Comment: How is possible that is returning but not printing?, Because if it appears as None, I can't do anything with that final list. I think that i'm not understanding the problem

Comment: You only return something when `if(sinRep == sinRep_AUX)` succeeds. If you finish the loop without this condition being true, the function ends without returning anything.

Comment: You also don't return anything when `if sinRep == dondeborrar` succeeds.

Comment: Hum, thats fine, I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only return something when `if sinRep == dondeborrar` fails and then during the loop `if(sinRep == sinRep_AUX)` succeeds.

You can solve these problems by moving the `return` statement to the end of the function.

```
def elimina_Rep(dondeborrar, cantidadNecesaria, fichcompleto):
    sinRep = []                                                 # Donde almacenaremos las NO repetidas
    sinRep_AUX = []                                             # Para borrar en la borrada, (varios ciclos de borrado)
    for elem in dondeborrar:                                    # Primera busqueda de elementos duplicados
        if(elem not in sinRep): sinRep.append(elem)             # Obtenemos una lista sin repeticiones
    if sinRep == dondeborrar : pass                             # Comprobamos que haya diferencia de cantidad entre ambas
    else:
        while(sinRep != sinRep_AUX):
            dif = (cantidadNecesaria - len(sinRep))             # Obtenemos cuantos elementos hemos borrado
            for i in range(0,dif):                              # Generamos tantas nuevas entradas como las que hemos borrado
                sinRep.append(random.choice(fichcompleto))      # Obtenemos una nueva lista completa (pero con posibles repeticiones)    
            for j in sinRep:                                    # Comprobamos que no haya repeticiones de la primera busqueda
                if(j not in sinRep_AUX):                        # Segunda busqueda de elementos duplicados  
                    sinRep_AUX.append(j)                        # Obtenemos una lista sin repeticiones sinRep_AUX desde la primera sin rep  
            if(sinRep == sinRep_AUX): 
                break
            else:
                sinRep = sinRep_AUX
                sinRep_AUX = []  
    return sinRep_AUX
```